# Displaying a SharePoint List from another team site in Sharepoint Online (office 365)

Tags: sharepoint, list, ms-office, office365

I'm looking for solution to office 365 and sharepoint online like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93558/Displaying-a-SharePoint-List-from-another-team-sit.aspx

I'll try to displaying a sharepoint list from another team site, like in this article but with no results.

I want to display items from List A on Site A to List B on site B.
(e.g.:

```
http://company.sharepoint.com/SiteA/Lists/ListA    
http://company.sharepoint.com/SiteB/Lists/ListB
```

And result:

“The server returned a non-specific error when trying to get data from the data source. Check the format and content of your query and try again. If the problem persist, contact the server administrator

Please help!

Comment: you have to give more details... what results did you get ? what did you tried ? Refer to [ask] page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a basic solution that uses AHAH to display a snapshot of a view in another site:

http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/default.aspx

(cross-site snapshot)

For your issue, you'll need to povide more details. For example: is it for authenticated or anonymous users? Which Office 365 plan?

Comment: Office 365 plan - E1. For authenticated users.

Comment: My simple method will allow you to display a A view on site B, or a B view on site A. Did your error happen after a SharePoint Designer customization?

Comment: Yes, after SP Designer customization